# SQL to check when pairs don't match

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, data-partitioning

I am using SQL Server 2012 I have the following sample data

```
Date        Type    Symbol      Price
6/30/1995   gaus    313586U72   109.25
6/30/1995   gbus    313586U72   108.94
6/30/1995   csus    NES         34.5
6/30/1995   lcus    NES         34.5
6/30/1995   lcus    NYN         40.25
6/30/1995   uaus    NYN         40.25
6/30/1995   agus    SRR         10.25
6/30/1995   lcus    SRR         0.45
7/1/1995    gaus    313586U72   109.25
7/1/1995    gbus    313586U72   108.94
```

I want to filter out when symbol and price match. It's ok if type doesn't match. Thus with the above data I would expect to only see

```
Date        Type    Symbol      Price
6/30/1995   gaus    313586U72   109.25
6/30/1995   gbus    313586U72   108.94
6/30/1995   agus    SRR         10.25
6/30/1995   lcus    SRR         0.45
7/1/1995    gaus    313586U72   109.25
7/1/1995    gbus    313586U72   108.94
```

NES and NYN have been filtered out because their symbol and price matches.

I was thinking of using Partition and row number, but I am not sure how to pair and filter rows using that or another function.

*** **UPDATE** I will be testing the replies. I should have mentioned I just want to see duplicates for symbol and price that occur on the same date. Also the table is called duppri

Comment: I just noticed your edit; to look for duplicates on the same date you can add another condition to my answers, see this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29d67/1

Comment: @jpw  I got your original query to work by adding the date line as you indicated. One question what does the select 1 part of the query do?

Comment: When you use `exists` the only thing of interest is whether the query returns something, not what it returns. Using `select 1` is just a way of indicating that the columns aren't important - plus it makes the query shorter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use the `exists` predicate with a correlated subquery that checks that the specific symbol have more than one price.:

```
select * from table1 t
where exists (
  select 1
  from table1
  where symbol = t.symbol
  and price <> t.price);
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d6d40e/4)

This would return:

```
|                   Date | Type |    Symbol |  Price |
|------------------------|------|-----------|--------|
| June, 30 1995 02:00:00 | gaus | 313586U72 | 109.25 |
| June, 30 1995 02:00:00 | gbus | 313586U72 | 108.94 |
| June, 30 1995 02:00:00 | agus |       SRR |  10.25 |
| June, 30 1995 02:00:00 | lcus |       SRR |   0.45 |
| July, 01 1995 02:00:00 | gaus | 313586U72 | 109.25 |
| July, 01 1995 02:00:00 | gbus | 313586U72 | 108.94 |
```

Edit: inspiried by Gordon Linoffs clever answer another option could be to use `avg()` as a windowed function:

```
select Date, Type, Symbol, Price  
from (
  select Date, Type, Symbol, Price, avg = avg(price) over (partition by symbol) 
  from table1) a
where avg <> price;
```

Edit: with a check to ensure only duplicates on the same date are returned: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29d67/1

Comment: Upvote for the window function part. But how about using `count distinct` as window function ?

Comment: That would be even more straightforward.

Comment: ... I just tried it, and also read now that `distinct` is not supported with `partition by`. (only `count`, without `distinct`). But perhaps it will be a future feature in SQL Server. There are user votes for this already.

Comment: Yes, but actually it is a part of the ANSI standard. SQL Server just has not implemented everything from the standard. BTW, in Oracle, it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

I would approach this using window functions:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             min(price) over (partition by symbol) as minprice,
             max(price) over (partition by symbol) as maxprice
      from sample s
     ) s
where minprice <> maxprice;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to use a `count distinct` as window function, instead of using min and max ? *[NB: Upvote. There should be much more use of window functions]*

Comment: Reg. the `count distinct`: I just found that `distinct` is not supported with `partition by`. (only `count`). Perhaps it will be a future feature in SQL Server. There are user votes already.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-select with `GROUP BY` combined with `HAVING COUNT DISTINCT` to find "bad" symbols:

```
select * from your_table
where symbol not in
(
  select symbol
  from your_table
  group by symbol
  having count(distinct price) > 1
)
```