# CASE Statement inside a subquery

Tags: sql, case

I was able to create the following query after help from the post below

```
select * from duppri t
where exists (
  select 1
  from duppri
  where symbolUP = t.symbolUP
  AND date = t.date
  and price <> t.price)
  ORDER BY date
```

[SQL to check when pairs don't match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206608/sql-to-check-when-pairs-dont-match?noredirect=1#comment50424494_31206608)

I have now realized that I need to add a case statement to indicate when all the above criteria fits, but the type value is equal between duppri and t.duppri. This occurs because of case sensitivity. This query is an attempt to clean up a portfolio accounting system that unfortunately allowed numerous duplicates because it didn't have strong referential integrity or constraints.

I would like the case statement to produce the column 'isMatch'

```
Date      |Type|Symbol   |SymbolUP |Concatt      |Price |IsMatch
6/30/1995 |gaus|313586U72|313586U72|gaus313586U72|109.25|Different
6/30/1995 |gbus|313586U72|313586U72|gbus313586U72|108.94|Different
6/30/1995 |agus|SRR      |SRR      |agusSRR      |10.25 |Different
6/30/1995 |lcus|SRR      |SRR      |lcusSRR      |0.45  |Different
11/27/1996|lcus|LLY      |LLY      |lcusLLY      |76.37 |Matched
11/27/1996|lcus|lly      |LLY      |lcusLLY      |76    |Matched
11/28/1996|lcus|LLY      |LLY      |lcusLLY      |76.37 |Matched
11/28/1996|lcus|lly      |LLY      |lcusLLY      |76    |Matched
```

I tried the following CASE statement but it is creating errors

```
SELECT * from duppri t
where exists (
  select 1,
  CASE IsMatch WHEN [type] = [t.TYPE] THEN 'Matched' ELSE 'Different' END
  from duppri
  where symbolUP = t.symbolUP
  AND date = t.date
  and price <> t.price) 

  ORDER BY date
```

Comment: When you give a `CASE` like `SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column] <> [column]`, how do you expect it to return any values? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: This query works. I want it to be a case statement select * from duppri t
where exists (
  select 1
  from duppri
  where symbolUP = t.symbolUP
  AND type = t.type
  AND date = t.date
  and price <> t.price)
  ORDER BY date

Comment: Actually this works if you post it as an answer I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use window functions, if I understand correctly:

```
select d.*,
       (case when mint = maxt
             then 'Matched' else 'Different'
        end)
from (select d.*, 
             min(type) over (partition by symbolup, date) as mint,
             max(type) over (partition by symbolup, date) as maxt,
             min(price) over (partition by symbolup, date) as minp,
             max(price) over (partition by symbolup, date) as maxp
      from duppri d
     ) d
where minp <> maxp
order by date;
```

Comment: This looks better indeed.

Comment: I gotta say this is indeed useful.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery used with the exists predicate can't and won't return anything other than true/false but you can accomplish what you want using a subquery like this, which should work:

```
select 
  *, 
  (select 
   CASE when count(distinct type) = 1 THEN 'Matched' ELSE 'Different' END
   from duppri
   where symbol = t.symbol and date = t.date
  ) IsMatch
from duppri t
where exists (
  select 1
  from duppri
  where symbol = t.symbol
  and price <> t.price);
```